# Change mouse curser to look like you can click on an element that isn't a button or a link

Tags: css

When you hover your mouse over a button or a link, the curser changes design to reflect that the element is clickable, but when hovering the mouse over an element with the onClick() function, it doesn't.

Is there a way to replicate this behavior on elements with the onClick() function?

Comment: You can change it with css. Load images and more. Check for: CSS Syntax
"cursor: value;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add css property **cursor** to that element.

```
.yourElement {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for: CSS Syntax **cursor: value;**

Here you can find a list of the cursor css options:

[CSS cursor Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

The cursor can also be an image:

```
.custom {
  /* The second value here is a fallback. */
  cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;

  /* You may need coordinates to adjust the pointer
     for example, the custom cursor is circular and you want
     the middle to be where you click */
  cursor: url(target.svg) 15 15, move;
}
```

From : [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/)